# CAKeyframeAnimation on CAEmitterCell color not working

Tags: ios, core-animation

I tried everything but I can't animate the color property of a CAEmitterCell with a CAKeyframeAnimation. The strange thing is: I can animate possibly almost everything else (haven't tried everything, but it seems that way). For example: Animating the backgroundColor of the CAEmitterLayer containing the CAEmitterCell is no problem. Also animating the CAEmitterCell scale works fine.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
let cell = CAEmitterCell()
...
cell.name = "main"
emitter.emitterCells = [cell]

let keyPath = "emitterCells.main.color"
// Uncomment this to see that the keyPath works correctly:
//emitter.setValue(UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor, forKeyPath: keyPath)
...
let backColorPath = "backgroundColor"
// Use this to see that color animation is basically possible:
//let anim2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: backColorPath)
let anim2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
anim2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
anim2.duration = 5
anim2.keyTimes = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
anim2.repeatCount = 20
anim2.values = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.cyan.cgColor,
            UIColor.magenta.cgColor]
emitter.add(anim2, forKey: "coloring")
```

Has anyone any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Gist playground can be found here: https://gist.github.com/JD-CSTx/fc0e55d4dcfcfed87eb31ecbb18fc979

Comment: I filed a bug at apple for this behavior, I expect them to fix it in iOS 11, more likely 12, or never, given their usual update cycle.
At the time of this comment iOS 10.2 is the latest iOS.

Comment: My latest info from Apple is that the bug is fixed, I will test it if iOS 11 comes out, because it seems the bugfix isn't included in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug inside the Apple libraries, they fixed it in iOS 11.